# Forgot to put brown and white sugar in cookie dough

Tags: baking, cake, dough, sugar, cookies

I made cookie dough. I already put white chocolate chips and so on. I forgot to put in brown and white sugar... How can I fix this?

Comment: Put the sugar in now, before you bake it?

Comment: Is it a cookie-recipe based on butter creamed with sugar? If yes, please answer this and wait a bit for my answer. If not, you should be fine adding the sugar now :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forgot to add sugar to cookies](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/forgot-to-add-sugar-to-cookies)

Comment: this is butter and peanut butter cream together then add sugar

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the cookies are baked now, but still:

If you increase the amount of dough, will you be in trouble?
You could just add the sugar now, but that will most likely mess up the texture (still, they are chocolate chip cookies, they are always good ^^)

Get the sugar you missed the first time.
Calculate your recipe down to the smallest amount you can make (this will most likely be whatever amount you reach when using only one egg).
Start this second batch as usual, but try to incorporate at least part of the "first batch"-sugar to the creamed butter... cream this REALLY well.
Finish remaining dough, as normal, adding any sugar you could not cream with the flour.
Fold both batches together.

This way, you should get at least some of the texture that the creaming creates :).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the sugar now, what the issue is and will be is that the chocolate will get pulverized some. That's why chips or fruit is added last or folded in.