# Creaming butter seperately on its own, then adding the sugar and beating them together vs simply creaming butter and sugar together (the regular way)?

Tags: baking, cake, cookies

Would there be any difference in the end result?  Usually you beat both the sugar and butter together but what if you instead, were to start by creaming  the butter on its own at first, then adding the sugar to the whipped butter and beating them  both together?  Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at the answer to this question and see if it answers your question as well: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/what-is-the-purpose-of-creaming-butter-with-sugar-in-cookie-recipes?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of creaming butter with sugar in cookie recipes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/what-is-the-purpose-of-creaming-butter-with-sugar-in-cookie-recipes)

Comment: I'm not sure if it answered my question.   My hypothetical method (cream butter seperately and then add sugar and continue beating) was not specifically addressed.  Is there something I'm missing?  I appreciate your help by the way.

Comment: From the accepted answer: "It has recently been discovered that cookie dough is different from cake batters. Sugar is part of the structure of the cookie and not just a sweetener, tenderizer, and browning agent. It forms the base upon which the fats and the starch granules of the flour are embedded. The sugar needs to dissolve for the matrix to form."

Comment: Now, if you're asking about cake, then it is a different question, but if so you need to edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.   I meant in terms of the amount of leavening provided.

Comment: So .. cream the butter and then add the sugar later, but *still* cream the sugar with the butter?  So the only difference would be whether you add the sugar when the butter is still cubes?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Seems very unlikely to make a difference; I agree that's not a duplicate question, though.  Please edit your original question to make it very clear what you're asking.